# Access structs through pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm working with linked lists. I'm having trouble accessing the data contained in a struct through a pointer. Here is my code:

```
void insertNode(Node **head, int num) {
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode -> num = num;

    while (head->next) {    <-----problematic code


    }
```

}

I've passed the address of the head pointer of the list into the function.

```
Node *list = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(Node));
Node *head = list;
insertNode(&head, randNum);
```

I keep getting an error that says "request for member "next" in something not a structure or union.

Comment: I'd change the function to `void insertNode(Node **hptr, int num)`, and then declare a local variable as `Node *head = *hptr;` That simplifies the syntax inside the function. If the function updates `head`, you'll need to copy that change back to the original with `*hptr = head;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(*head)->next` in your loop.

Reason is simple, you send `Node**` but expect that it will work like a `Node*`, which is not correct.

Comment: Oh jeez, I just wasn't putting the parentheses. I guess it was trying to dereference the entire thing instead of just head.

Answer (score 4):

`Node **head` is a pointer to a pointer to a `Node`. So `head->` is dereferencing a pointer to a pointer and therefore gives you a pointer. A pointer is not a struct or union, hence the error. You can use:

```
(*head)->
```

to dereference the underlying node.